# Do I need to add an article before "weekend"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, articles

When I’m going to have a weekend, can I say “**It’s weekend,**” or do I need to add ‘a’ or ‘the’ in front of the word *weekend*?

Comment: What does “going to have a weekend” mean?  Weekends are not things which people normally “have”.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm having one right now. It's pretty sweet. You should let me hook you up.

Comment: Sounds like a euphanism to me! ;-)

Comment: This question would probably work better on ELL. [Commit now!](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is incomprehensible as asked. It should be asked this way:

Is the sentence "It's weekend" grammatical, or should it be "It's the weekend"?

> "It's weekend" is abnormal and ungrammatical.
>
> "It's Saturday" is normal, grammatical,  and idiomatic.
>
> "It's **the** weekend" is normal, grammatical, and idiomatic.
>
> "It's **a** weekend" is normal, grammatical, and idiomatic.

The latter two sentences have slightly different meanings. "It's the weekend" is an announcement about the date, as in: "Today is Tuesday. Do you know what that means?" "It's a weekend" is the answer to a question about the part of the week two particular days are, as in: "This flyer says that the convention's on March 16-17, 2013. {When's that? / Are those weekdays or is it a weekend?}" "It's a weekend."

Answer (score 6):

I tried to think of an instance where I'd use *weekend* without an article, but it was hard to do, no matter where I put the word in the sentence:

> *We need to find a good weekend to go fishing.
>
>   Her favorite time of the week is the weekend.
>
>   The weekend is almost over!*

That last one could be modified a little, where we wouldn't need the word *the*:

> *My weekend is almost over!*

but I still need a word in place of the article, to serve as a qualifier:

> *No weekend is complete without a nap.*

When I use the plural, though, I don't need a leading article anymore:

> *When can we get together? Weekends would be best for me.
>
>   I love to go golfing on weekends.*